# Strange Binomial question.

Tags: binomial-theorem

So I revising Binomials until I came across this question...

i) Given that $a=y+d $ use the binomial expansion of $(y+d)^{n},$ where $n$ is positive integer, to show that $a^{n}-y^{n-1}(y+nd) $ is divisible by  $d^{2}$

ii) Hence show that if $a$ is the first term, $d$ the common difference, $L$ the $n$-th term of an arithmetic progression, then $a^{n}-L(a-d)^{n-1}$ is divisible by $d^{2}$

I could do the first part but I am stuck on the next....

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $a-d=y$, $L = a + (n-1)d = y+nd$.

Comment: Yes I managed to get that far, but I am stuck on what to do next... But thanks your time~

Comment: But then i) implies ii).

Comment: You have no idea how hard I just facepalmed myself yes I did realise that i) implies ii) but i'm just not thinking properly today